# Spin not taking blackboard value instead it always taking 0

Tags: ros2, spin, nav2

In ros2 behavior server Spin Action is not accepting spin_dist as a blackboard variable, the variable will be an Output port of another behavior tree node. Check the code below,

```
<MyNode input="something" output="${angle_to_rotate}"/>
<Spin spin_dist="${angle_to_rotate}" server_name="spin" />
```

Here Spin Node is getting initialized with 0 as spin_dist at once, not taking input from blackboard variable while ticking the Node at Run Time.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Vignesh, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Did you set angle_to_rotate? Can you check that that blackboard variable has a value?

Comment: Hi @StevenMacenski, i get angle_to_rotate as the output port of another while the behavior tree is running, but Spin is setting the spin_dist at OnConfigure function this will call at initialization only so i am updating this angle_to_rotate value while ticking so it is not going to apply, in order to make this accept i've updated on_tick function of spin with getting spin_dist input whenever it is ticking

Comment: `void SpinAction::on_tick()
  {
    double dist;
    getInput("spin_dist", dist);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is, Spin is getting input from blackboard at the time of initialization only, to make Spin to get input on Running we need to update the on_tick function of Spin Action.

```
  void SpinAction::on_tick()
  {
    double dist;
    getInput("spin_dist", dist);
    RCLCPP_WARN(node_->get_logger(), "Angle from spin action %.2f", dist);
    double time_allowance;
    getInput("time_allowance", time_allowance);
    goal_.target_yaw = dist;
    goal_.time_allowance = rclcpp::Duration::from_seconds(time_allowance);
    getInput("is_recovery", is_recovery_);
    if (is_recovery_)
    {
      increment_recovery_count();
    }
  }
```